# Is it possible to submit paper to peer-reviewed journal without affiliation?

Tags: paper-submission, affiliation

I have conducted an evaluation on effectiveness of training interventions on elderly clients in a non-government organization. I would like to share the results by submitting paper to peer-reviewed journal. However, owing to policy of the organization, i was told to submit the paper on personal capacity. I would like to know if peer-reviewed journal accept paper from investigator without affiliation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to submit to almost all journals outwith affiliation. Just list yourself as an unaffiliated researcher. This answer covers well the additional hurdles you may have to jump ([Who can submit papers to peer-reviewed journals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/who-can-submit-papers-to-peer-reviewed-journals)).

Comment: If you know that the question has already been addressed here, just flag to close as a duplicate. See [what is flagging](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).